# listview item click animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have list view with several items. when user clicks on single item, right now i am opening new activity which has more detail. I want to apply animation here in way that, when user clicks on item, the new activity comes from slide in from right. I tried various ways but i couldn't get it done. here is my code.

I am getting listview items from CustomBaseAdapter.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                CustomBaseAdapter mAdapter = (CustomBaseAdapter)list.getAdapter();
                AddVO listItem = (AddVO) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent data = new Intent(this, NewActivityToBeOpenedUsingAnimation.class);
                data.putExtra("VO", listItem);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,data);

                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ViewExpenseActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                list.startAnimation(animation);
                startActivityForResult(data, 2);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: your below code is not showing any animations on click of listview row

Answer (score 3):

i got to resolved it.

Put below code in activity:

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left);
```

slide_right.xml in (res/anim) folder

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

slide_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```